# Asking for user input with java setters and getters

Tags: java

how would i ask the user for the radius? I'm pretty sure it will be an easy fix but i'm just not sure how to do it. Here is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CircleDriver
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        Circle circle1 = new Circle();
        circle1.setRadius(20);
        System.out.println("Enter the radius of a circle " + circle1.getRadius());
        System.out.println("Area = " + circle1.calculateArea());
        System.out.println("Diameter = " + circle1.calculateDiameter());
        System.out.println("Circumference = " + circle1.calculateCircumference());


    }

}
```

Circle class :

```
public class Circle
{

    private double radius;
    private final double PI = 3.14159;

    /**
     * this method calculates the area of the given radius
     * @return
     */
    public double calculateArea() {

        double area;

        area = (PI * radius * radius);

        return area;
    }
    /**
     * this method calculates the diameter of the given radius
     * @return
     */
    public double calculateDiameter() {

        double diameter;

        diameter = (radius * 2);

        return diameter;

    }
    /**
     * this method calculates the circumference of the given radius
     * @return
     */
    public double calculateCircumference() {

        double circumference;

        circumference = (2 * PI * radius);

        return circumference;

    }

    /**
     * this method sets the radius of the object
     * @param radius
     */

    public void setRadius(double radius) {

        this.radius = radius;
    }

    /**
     * this radius returns the radius given
     * @return
     */
    public double getRadius() {

        return radius;
    }

}
```

Comment: All you need to do is circle1.setRadius(input.nextDouble());

Comment: You have a `Scanner`, why aren't you using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
System.out.println("Enter the radius pls :");
try {    
    circle1.setRadius(input.nextDouble());
} catch (InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("ERROR : Invalid input !");
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? Do not forget to valid. :)

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure this out for like an hour and now i finally realize how easy the fix was!

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a Scanner called `input`, but you're not using it. Instead, you're hard-coding the value `20`.

Try this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Circle circle1 = new Circle();
System.out.print("Enter the radius of a circle: ");
circle1.setRadius(input.nextDouble());
System.out.println("Area = " + circle1.calculateArea());
System.out.println("Diameter = " + circle1.calculateDiameter());
System.out.println("Circumference = " + circle1.calculateCircumference());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Circle circle1 = new Circle();
System.out.println("Enter the radius of a circle ");
int radius = input.nextInt();
```

There are several ways in getting an input from the user including BufferedReader, Console, Scanner etc. Above is an example using Scanner class. Now use the above radius value in your further calculations.